# Loop through file names in a Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like a batch script to all the text documents in a folder.
This is what I have managed so far:

```
@ECHO off
title Test
set dir1=C:\Users\Family\Desktop\Example

:Start
cls
echo 1. test loop
echo 2. Quit
set /p choice=I choose (1,2):
if %choice%==1 goto test
if %choice%==2 exit

:test
cls
echo running loop test 
FOR %%n in (%dir1% *.txt) DO echo %dir1%\%%n
echo Done
pause
```

What I would like outputted is:

```
running loop test
C:\Users\Family\Desktop\Example\doc 1.txt
C:\Users\Family\Desktop\Example\doc 2.txt
Done
```

**But I Get this:**

```
running loop test
C:\Users\Family\Desktop\Example\C:\Users\Family\Desktop\Example
C:\Users\Family\Desktop\Example\doc 1.txt
C:\Users\Family\Desktop\Example\doc 2.txt
Done
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main problem seems to be the space between (%dir1% *.txt)

It could be

```
@ECHO off
title Test
set "dir1=C:\Users\Family\Desktop\Example"

:Start
cls
echo 1. test loop
echo 2. Quit
set /p choice=I choose (1,2):
if %choice%==1 goto test
if %choice%==2 exit

:test
cls
echo running loop test 
FOR %%X in ("%dir1%\*.txt") DO echo %%~dpnX
echo Done
pause
```

The quotes are for avoiding problems with spaces or other special characters in the path.

**EDIT:**
The `%%~dpnX` is for expanding the filename of `%%X` to
`d`=drive(C:)
`p`=path(\Users\Family\Desktop\Example)
`n`=filename(test1) (without extension)

`f`=full filename(C:\Users\Family\Desktop\Example\test1.txt).

The possible modifiers are explained here **FOR /?**

Comment: Thank You that worked perfectly.
Could you explain %%~dpfX to me?

Comment: `%%~nX` just filename (test1), filename with extension - `%%~nxX` (test1.txt).

Comment: To clarify: note that in his code `%%X` is the whole filename that was found. The other pieces `~dpn` are modifiers to the `%%X`. So as user 2nd said, use the `~n` modifier on the variable to output just the file by calling `echo %%~nX`