# find and replace in multiple batch files

Tags: batch-file

I have over 1000 batch files in a folder.

Is there a way to run a script to find a particular text string (lets say Apples) and replace Apples with (Mangos) in all the files?

Thanks in advance

Shei

Comment: Check out "Swiss file knife": http://www.stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html

Comment: Check this: https://findandreplace.codeplex.com/documentation. I know it is a old question but Google brings me here and I was unable to see a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find many examples here in stackoverflow to do'it in pure `batch-script`.

Take a look here for the `replace` part:
[How to replace string inside a bat file with command line parameter string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816178/how-to-replace-string-inside-a-bat-file-with-command-line-parameter-string)
Or here:
[How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir?rq=1)

And here:
[Loop through file names in a Batch Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663928/batch-script-loop-through-file-names)
and here:
[Iterate all files in a directory using a 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/batch-scripting-iterating-over-files-in-a-directory)
to `loop`over the files in a directory....

Those are just a few ones, but there's many more.

Now If you are able to consider a third-party software...
... I can't go without recommend [WinGrep for Windows](http://www.wingrep.com/), very very usefull, and of course, auto-replace for search results (also regEx search)

Good luck any way

---

[edit]
*(I add this because st2 was the accepted solution)*
I'm also a SublimeText user, and for me, [ST2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) + [winGrep](http://www.wingrep.com/) + [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) it's a fantastic trio for development under Windows.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Sublime Text (it's a free unlimited evaluation) to 'Find > Find in Files'. The find and replace options will appear at the bottom. Type 'apples' in 'Find:', type your location in 'Where', and type 'mangos' in 'replace', then click 'Replace.' Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks mate,
I was wondering if there a solution which would not require any third party software??

Comment: @Shei7141 then don't mark it as solved yet. people generally ignore solved questions when looking for problems to help solve :-)

Comment: The reason, I marked it solved was simply because this program does the trick.... but you're right... unmarked now....

If anyone know a script that would be great.... I can do find and replace for one file.... but can't seem to get my head around running global find and replace on all the files in the specified folder...

Comment: What an awesome feature and nice design!

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple solution using a FOR loop coupled with a [hybrid JScript/batch utility called REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053). The utility is pure script that runs on any modern Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party executables required. It performs a regex search and replace on stdin, and writes the result to stdout.

Assuming REPL.BAT is in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere within your PATH:

```
for %%F in (*.bat) do (
  type "%%F"|repl Apples Mangos >"%%F.new"
  move /y "%%F.new" "%%F"
)
```

REPL.BAT has many options that make it quite powerful for such a small bit of code. Complete documentation is built into the script.

Comment: Dave, the plain for loop will process some files twice.  for /F is needed.

Comment: @foxidrive - Are you sure? That would surprise me, though I haven't tested. I thought since the modified file has the same name as the original, it would never reprocess.

Comment: I just tested it and it doesn't reprocess the same filenames - it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up installing and using [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for the OP same goal while batch programming.

Loaded up Notepad++, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, `Find in Files` tab, then filled the fields like this and struck the `Replace in Files` button.

[image]