# Batch script to replace specific string in multiple files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I don't have much experience with batch scripts, and my employer has asked me write a batch script that can be run to find and replace some text inside all matching files in the directory.

I've tried searching this and there's a tonne of resource, which I've used to get me this far:

```
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "search=<employeeloginid>0"
    set "replace=<employeeloginid>"

    set "textFile=TimeTEQ20170103T085714L.XML"

    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        >>"%textFile%" echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
```

This will find all occurrences of `<employeeloginid>0` and replace it with `<employeeloginid>` inside a **set file** - in this case `TimeTEQ20170103T085714L.XML`.

I now need to tweak this to run on all files that **start with** `TimeTEQ` and **end with** `.xml`

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663992/1739852) which shows how to do all files in a directory, but I don't know how I would tweak it to suit my needs here.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Advice.If its not requirement to use batch - make your life easier - use a scripting language. I would prefer python, but you can choose whatever you like. Multiple file content parsing is possible, but bad thing to do in the batch.

Comment: @Drako that was my immediate thought too, however it is a requirement as it needs to go to a client and they require it as a batch file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply wrap around a standard [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html), like this:

```bat
@echo off 
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "search=<employeeloginid>0"
set "replace=<employeeloginid>"

set "textFile=TimeTEQ*.xml"
set "rootDir=."

for %%j in ("%rootDir%\%textFile%") do (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~j" ^& break ^> "%%~j"') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        >>"%%~j" echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
```

---

If you want to process matching files also in the sub-folders, use a [`for /R` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html):

```bat
@echo off 
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "search=<employeeloginid>0"
set "replace=<employeeloginid>"

set "textFile=TimeTEQ*.xml"
set "rootDir=."

for /R "%rootDir%" %%j in ("%textFile%") do (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~j" ^& break ^> "%%~j"') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        >>"%%~j" echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

You can surround the loop you got currently with another one going through all files in the directory that match your pattern like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%n in ('dir /b ^| findstr /r "TIMETEQ.*\.xml') do (
```

and change the header of your current loop to:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~n" ^& break ^> "%%~n" ') do (
```

and `>>"%textFile%" echo(!line!` to

```
>>"%%~n" echo(!line!
```

So in total the new script should look like this:

```
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "search=<employeeloginid>0"
    set "replace=<employeeloginid>"

    set "textFile=TimeTEQ20170103T085714L.XML"

    for /f "delims=" %%n in ('dir /a-d /b ^| findstr /r "TIMETEQ.*\.xml') do (

        for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~n" ^& break ^> "%%~n" ') do (
            set "line=%%i"
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
            >>"%%~n" echo(!line!
            endlocal
        )
    )
```

Explanation:

The new added outer loop goes through the output of the command `dir /b ^| findstr /r "TIMETEQ.*\.xml` which itself contains the result of a regex search over the output of the `dir` command with `/b` switch to show only the filenames and `/a-d` to execlude directories from the search.

Then I changed `%filename%` to the parameter of the loop -> `%%~n` with `~` to remove potential surrounding double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

for people still searching this on google, the easy way is to open all files containing the text needed to be replaced in notepad++, press ctrl+F, click replace, type in what you want to find and replace and click replace all, then save all.

Comment: the `all matching files` part would make this very painful, so this answer isn't helpful.

Comment: I found this answer useful - notepad++ as of version 7.9 can replace strings within files of a directory. I had to replace NCOLS to ncols in 60 files. This worked like a charm with the  ctrl+F replace in directories.