# How to deal with special characters (<, >, ", =) in string search/replace

Tags: batch-file, replace, cmd, special-characters

I adapted this script from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41542554) on Stack Overflow. Script works, but has incorrect output because of special characters (`<`, `>`, `"`, `=`) in the search query.

Basically, I just need to find `<script src="https://d1tdp7z6w94jbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` and remove it.

```
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "search=<script src="https://d1tdp7z6w94jbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>"
set "replace="

set "textFile=index.html"
set "rootDir=."

for %%j in ("%rootDir%\%textFile%") do (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~j" ^& break ^> "%%~j"') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        >>"%%~j" echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)
endlocal
```

I have found other threads on Stack Overflow asking the same question, but I can't understand their implementations and how to apply them to this script.

Comment: This is the original script:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542554/batch-script-to-replace-specific-string-in-multiple-files

Comment: My tests are showing that the `<` and `>` are breaking things, not the quotes. What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Is it really necessary to use batch for this task? There's a lot of other tools which will do it much faster and better.

Comment: Thanks @SomethingDark, really appreciate you letting me know. The problem is that the search criteria is showing up in the output files. I assumed this to be because of the " but thankyou for clarifying.

Comment: @montonero, it's for ease of use (no host required to run the script) and future configurability without requiring re-coding. Also, I'm not a coder, but am familiar with .BAT since you had to load MS-DOS from 3.5". :)

Comment: I just realised that the major problem are the `=`-signs, that's why I deleted my (apparently wrong) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56890348); finally I found [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37724410) dealing with exactly the same problem, which I once provided a solution for...

Comment: Thank you again @aschipfl. I tried the method you linked (repl-str.bat) and didn't have any luck when I ran this from inside another BAT file:
````repl-str.bat "index.php" "<script src=\x22https://d1tdp7z6w94jbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js\x22 type=\x22text/javascript\x22 integrity=\x22sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=\x22 crossorigin=\x22anonymous\x22></script>" "" "index.php"````

It gives the error "cscript.exe is not recognized.."
I even added the IF NOT EXIST lines which pass correctly.

Comment: Well, are you sure you copied the most recent version of the script `repl-str.bat` correctly? I cannot reproduce that, and where should `cscript.exe` come from, which is never called within my script? could you (temporarily) change `@echo off` to `@echo on` and check what line is causing the failure? and what is the exact encoding of your input file `index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Windows command processor `cmd.exe` is designed for executing commands and applications. It is not designed for file content modification purposes independent on type of file.

There are lots of script interpreters which have built-in support for modification of file contents like VBScript, JScript, PowerShell, Perl, Python, ... So best would be to use a different script interpreter than Windows command processor for this task, especially on search or replace string contain `"<=>|` which makes a file content modification with pure Windows command processor commands a nightmare.

However, this is an easy to achieve task with using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid to run a regular expression replace on a file using JScript.

```
@echo off
if not exist ".\index.html" goto :EOF
if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" goto :EOF

call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "[\t ]*<script src=\x22https://d1tdp7z6w94jbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js\x22 type=\x22text/javascript\x22 integrity=\x22sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=\x22 crossorigin=\x22anonymous\x22></script>[\t ]*\r?\n?" "" /M /F ".\index.html" /O -
```

The batch file first checks if there is an `index.html` file in current directory and immediately exits if this condition is not true, see [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

The batch file **JREPL.BAT** must be stored in same directory as the batch file with the code above. For that reason the batch file checks next if **JREPL.BAT** really exists in directory of the batch file and exits if this condition is not true.

Next the batch file calls **JREPL.BAT** to do a case-sensitive regular expression replace with replace string being an empty string.

The search string is mainly the string which should be removed from the file.

Each `"` in search string is replaced by `\x22` which is an expression to search for a character with hexadecimal code value `22` which is the code value of character `"` to be able to specify this string on Windows command line as one argument string enclosed in double quotes.

The main search string does not contain any character with a special regular expression meaning and therefore no other character must be escaped with a backslash to be interpreted as literal character by regular expression function of JScript.

The main search string also does not contain any character with a special Windows command processor meaning even inside a double quoted argument string like percent sign `%`. Each `%` inside the searched string would be needed to be escaped with one more `%` to be interpreted as literal character by `cmd.exe` parsing this command line before calling the other batch file with the already parsed arguments.

The search expression starts with `[\t ]*` to remove additionally 0 or more horizontal tabs or normal spaces left to the string to remove. The string to remove is usually in an HTML file on a separate line indented with tabs or spaces and the goal is to remove also those indenting whitespaces.

The search expression ends with `[\t ]*\r?\n?` to remove additionally 0 or more horizontal tabs or normal spaces right to the string to remove, i.e. trailing whitespaces on the line, and one carriage return if existing at all, and one line-feed if existing at all.

So an entire line is removed from the file if the string to remove is on a separate line in the HTML file without or with leading tabs/spaces and without or with trailing tabs/spaces. But if the string to remove is on a line with other HTML tags, just the searched string and the tabs/spaces left and right to this string are removed from the HTML file. The **JREPL.BAT** option `/M` is used to be able to remove an entire line and not only the searched string within the line and leaving back an empty line on script tags being on a separate line.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains also `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 being the batch file itself.
- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `jrepl.bat /?`

Comment: WOW @Mofi, this is really amazing. The [\t ]* part was especially clever, great thinking!
JREPL.BAT looks great. (Have you seen that the help pages are more than half the filesize?! XD
I couldn't see any switches in there to recurse subdirectories. /s is standard for a few command line programs, but doesn't seem to be there in JREPL. Any thoughts on this? I have some other strings that need to be found & replaced, too, so recurse would be necessary.